# Best way to store user settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Yes, I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682089/rails-best-practice-to-store-user-settings). It seems old and I wanted to ask again, especially with the recent release of Rails 5.

What is the best way to store user settings in Rails? <s>It seems [has_easy](https://github.com/cjbottaro/has_easy) is a decent way.</s> [Rails-cached-settings](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached) also seems like a good way - but I dislike that there are no default values and it is... rather ambiguous.

Both of these options seem good, but how do they impact performance? If I only have three settings, is it better to have them directly on the model? What if I have ten?

Edit: has_easy is 8 years old, probably not the best option by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings for storing model specific settings with optional default values.
This stores the settings in a simple has_many association. The data is stored in a Proc.
I assume that a simple join will not have a big impact on performance.

Comment: We ended up using this. It was fine. We should've thought more about database design before we implemented it, though.

Answer (score 4):

I like starting out simple before making things too complex. If you only have three settings per user, it might not be a bad idea to start with them on the model. When it starts to get too complicated, then make the decision to switch to something more extensible. You will have a lot more information at that point to pick the right way to handle settings.

Comment: Late comment, but in case someone stumbles upon this: We knew we were going to have many settings, otherwise I would recommend this approach.