# Edit a serialized hash in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, hash

I'm serializing a hash that is stored in a `settings` field in a table, and would like to be able to edit that hash in a form field.

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :settings
end
```

But I just do `<%= f.text_area :settings %>` then the text area just shows the serialized data instead of the hash.

How can I get the hash to show in the text area?

Comment: What do you expect to see in the textarea?  Something like `{:foo=>'bar'}`?  One problem will be that when you submit the form the settings field will be serialized as a string, not as a hash, unless you add some logic to your app.  The logic should preferably go in the model.

Comment: Correct. I'd like to see `{:foo=>'bar'}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe setting up another accessor for your model would work.

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :settings
  attr_accessor :settings_edit

  before_save :handle_settings_edit, :if => lambda {|template| template.settings_edit.present? }

  def settings_edit
    read_attribute(:settings).inspect   # should display your hash like you want
  end

  protected
    def handle_settings_edit
      # You may want to perform eval in your validations instead of in a 
      # before_save callback, so that you can show errors on your form.
      begin
        self.settings = eval(settings_edit)
      rescue SyntaxError => e
        self.settings = settings_edit
      end
    end  
end
```

Then in your form use `<%= f.text_area :settings_edit %>`.

I have not tested any of this code, but in theory it should work.  Good luck!

**WARNING: Using `eval` like this is very dangerous, in this example a user could delete the entire Template table with one line in the edit box `Template.destroy_all`. Use a different method to convert the string to a hash if user input is involved.**

Comment: Actually...this doesn't seem to be working. When I edit the form and submit (to UPDATE), it doesn't save the changes to `settings`...it keeps the previous data.

Comment: Did something change?  Are you using `attr_accessible`?  If so, make sure you allow mass assignment to `settings_edit`.

Comment: Nothing changed and I'm not using `attr_accessible`.

Comment: This is close. The problem is that the statement "eval(settings_edit)" is reading the method you defined above.  I got this working by removing the method def settings_edit and instead adding the line "@template.settings_edit = @template.read_attribute(:settings).inspect" to my edit action in the controller.

Comment: Also, you should add and empty hash in the new action when you create the model, @template = Template.new( :settings => {} )

Comment: Using `eval` on user input is not safe. A malicious user could stick any Ruby code in form field and have it executed on your server.

Comment: I Agree with Wizard of Ogz, using an `eval` like that is super dangerous. That gives the user unlimited access to run whatever ruby code they want. Such as `Template.destroy_all`.

Comment: Use `self.settings = eval(@settings_edit)` instead of `self.settings = eval(settings_edit)`

Answer (score 2):

... or you could use something like this (without any logic in model):

```
<% @template.settings.each do |name, value| %>
  <div>
    <%= label_tag name %>
    <%= text_field_tag "template[settings][#{name}]", value %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but you would need more logic in your form to add a new key/value pair to the settings hash.

Comment: yep, and it will be pretty complex actually :) so this way works if you have pre-defined config key and don't want keys to be added or removed

Answer (score -2):

you should use something like

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :settings, Hash
end
```

Comment: Doesn't change the contents of the text_area