# Rails - best practice to store key/value hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my challenge.  I have a key/value set that I want to tie to a model.  These are my specific requirements:

- I want the hash to be stored as a serialized JSON object in the model's table instead of in a separate table
- I want to be able to pre-define the valid keys within the model itself
- I want to be able to set a strong type for each key and automatically perform validations.  I don't want to have to write validation functions for each individual attribute unless it needs a validation out of the basic data type scope.
- I would LOVE to be able to magically access the attributes inside a form generator (f.input :my_key) and have the form generator recognize that :my_key is of type :boolean and create a checkbox instead of a generic text input.  The same for other data types.

There are a few different ways to solve this problem, and lots of opinions for both.  I read over this answer from 5 years ago:

[Best approach to save user preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079711/best-approach-to-save-user-preferences)

It seems that many/most of those plugins have been abandoned.  Anything else come out in the last 5 years that matches my criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit open-ended, but as far as I can see your needs, they should be met with using [Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) gem.

Comment: It, indeed, was open ended.  Hashie looks promising for this use case.  Thanks for the tip!