# Best way to save personal user settings who are used on java desktop application app and website

Tags: java, mysql

I'm creating an application where i store all the users settings into a MySQL server. But now i got like something when tableOption3 = id25 then the users theme is red. I already got 5 such tables. And it going to get alot bigger. The user can use an mobile application that saves the personal settings for the website and java application and visa versa.

Do I have other options?
And I keep wondering what happens if there would be 100 personal option to be loaded. Would the user notice this in loading speed.

Comment: have you considered using a NOSQL db?

Comment: If you want to load and save user preferences only on login/logout in desktop app you can keep it in one class then serialize it during logout and again deserialize during login. Its not that time cosuming imho you wont even notice loading 100 preferences

Comment: I have no experience with NoSQL. But why would you prefer NOSQl in this case?

Comment: @ziker i will certainly look into this.We used this in class but  I can simply create a class with all the user settings and store it into a database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best approach to save user preferences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079711/best-approach-to-save-user-preferences)

Comment: this question should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079711/best-approach-to-save-user-preferences also @Fazovsky provided good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save these personal user settings somewhere and you will always want to use some sort of datastore, like: `SQL databases`, `NOSQL`, flat files.
I think that SQL databases are usually way to go, and having more then 100 personal options shouldn't degrade performance too much.

But my advice will be to avoid having multiple tables. You can achieve desired effect, with all properties stored for all users, by having `just one table`, i.e.:

```
 USER_ID | PROPERTY | PROPERTY_VALUE
 1       | COLOR    | RED
 2       | COLOR    | BLUE
 1       | FONT_SIZE| 12
 2       | FONT_SIZE| 14
etc
```

Comment: Great idea i will certainly give this a try. Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a drop-in solution for Java you can try [jsup](https://github.com/toolshed-cloud/jsup), which is a java library to store and fetch simple user preferences in SQL databases.

I am the author of jsup and write a lot of small applications/tools. I have often found the need to support user preferences and didn't find a suitable library that worked with different SQL databases, so I went ahead and created jsup.

It works with a variety of common SQL database types and is simple to get started with:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
    new AbstractModule() {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb");
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);

        // Be sure to specify the correct dialect.
        bind(Key.get(SQLDialect.class, UserPreferencesModule.UserPreferences.class)).toInstance(SQLDialect.H2);
        bind(Key.get(DataSource.class, UserPreferencesModule.UserPreferences.class)).toInstance(dataSource);
      }
    },
    new UserPreferencesModule());
UserPreferencesDb userPreferencesDb = injector.getInstance(UserPreferencesDb.class);
UserPreferencesAnalytics userPreferencesAnalytics = injector.getInstance(UserPreferencesAnalytics.class);

userPreferencesDb.setString("some-user", "ui", "theme", "default");
userPreferencesDb.setString("some-user", "ui", "display.timestamp.timezone", "UTC");
userPreferencesDb.addToSet("some-user", "app", "favorite.projects", ImmutableSet.of("prj1", "prj2"));
userPreferencesDb.setBoolean("some-user", "app", "email.on.failure", true);

System.out.println(userPreferencesDb.getString("some-user", "ui", "theme"));
System.out.println(userPreferencesDb.getString("some-user", "ui", "display.timestamp.timezone"));
System.out.println(userPreferencesDb.getSet("some-user", "app", "favorite.projects"));
System.out.println(userPreferencesDb.getBoolean("some-user", "app", "email.on.failure"));

System.out.println(userPreferencesAnalytics.getStringCategories());
System.out.println(userPreferencesAnalytics.getBooleanPreferencesByUser("app", "email.on.failure"));
```

In addition to a DB interface to store and fetch preferences, there is an analytics interface to get stats or make integration with other tools easier.

There are examples and more documentation on the GitHub page. If there are things you'd like added please open a ticket.